# Django permission classes not working on HTTPS server

Tags: python, django, nginx, https, permissions

My website was working fine on http servers but when I shifted it to https, django was unable to detect any permission class (including allow any). It was throwing "403 Permission Denied - Invalid Username/Password". I debugged the issue and found out that header needs to emptied before passing it. So I cleared my header by adding following in my nginx server :

```
proxy_set_header HTTP_AUTHORIZATION ''
```

This empties the Authorization Header and the site starts working for a while. But if there is any request with HTTP authorization, it also gets emptied and django permission classes do not get anything so they don't allow to access the method.

Please help with the situation.